# Не определяется 'length'

Tags: javascript

Есть две ошибки с length.
Cannot read property 'length' of undefined at type and typing.

```js
setTimeout(function typing() {

var fields = document.querySelectorAll('input');
var text = ["text", "textqwe", "textqweasd", "textqweasdzxc"];

function print (input, num, timeout) {
    setTimeout(function(){
        var i = 0;
        function type(){
            if (i <= text[num].length) {
        input.value = text[num].substr(0, i);
        setTimeout(type, 100);
            }
            console.log(text[num].length);
            i++;
        }
        type();
        console.log(type());
        if (num == 3) {
        setTimeout(
            function() {
            document.getElementById('postlogo_animation').className +=" postlogo-img"
            },text[num].length * 120);
        }
    }, timeout);
}

for (var b = 0; b < fields.length; b++) {
    var timeout = 0;
    var input = fields[b];
    if (b > 0) {
        for (var c = 0; c < b; c++) {
            timeout += text[c].length * 140
        }
    }
    print(input, b, timeout)
}}, 1000);
```

[image: Скрин консоли]

Comment: Почему тебе просто не взять и не отладить код?

Comment: Он не может прочитать length, потому что нет такого элемента. Чтоб посмотреть что есть и почему его нет - надо заглянуть в отладчик или в код.... например инпутов больше, чем элементов массива

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У вас инпутов больше, чем элементов массива. Добавьте в условие цикла проверку и на длинну массива тоже:

```js
setTimeout(function typing() {

var fields = document.querySelectorAll('input');
var text = ["text", "textqwe", "textqweasd", "textqweasdzxc"];

function print (input, num, timeout) {
    setTimeout(function(){
        var i = 0;
        function type(){
            if (i <= text[num].length) {
        input.value = text[num].substr(0, i);
        setTimeout(type, 100);
            }
            console.log(text[num].length);
            i++;
        }
        type();
        console.log(type());
        if (num == 3) {
        setTimeout(
            function() {
            // document.getElementById('postlogo_animation').className +=" postlogo-img"
            },text[num].length * 120);
        }
    }, timeout);
}

for (var b = 0; b < fields.length && b < text.length; b++) {
    var timeout = 0;
    var input = fields[b];
    for (var c = 0; c < b; c++) {
        timeout += text[c].length * 140
    }
    print(input, b, timeout)
}}, 1000);
```

```html
<input />
<input />
<input />
<input />
<input />
```

Comment: Darth, верно, в html был еще один инпут. Присвоил нужным инпутам класс, добавил в var fields = document.querySelectorAll('.input-auto'); и готово